# Stretch stopped working after parenting widget to layout pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am here with pyqt question again.
I think, this question was probably answered somewhere, but I can't phrase my problem properly in a way to find it in google, so sorry if it's duplicated the question.

I wrote simple code to show the problem I am facing.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QMenu, QWidget, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        btn_widget_a = QWidget()
        btn_layout_a = QHBoxLayout(btn_widget_a)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(btn_widget_a)

        btn_a = QPushButton()
        btn_layout_a.addWidget(btn_a)
        btn_a.setFixedSize(60, 60)

        btn_b = QPushButton()
        btn_layout_a.addWidget(btn_b)
        btn_b.setFixedSize(60, 60)

        tool_widget = QWidget()
        btn_layout_a.addWidget(tool_widget)
        tool_menu= QMenu(tool_widget)
        tool_menu.addMenu('Options')
        btn_a.setMenu(tool_menu)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Problem is this `btn_layout_a.addWidget(tool_widget)` when I add QMenu inside the widget in my layout, buttons don't stretch anymore when you resize your UI. Is there a way to fix it? I know that if simply delete `btn_layout_a.addWidget(tool_widget)` it will work properly, but thing is that unless I put it in a widget, QMenu doesn't work properly inside the software called Maya. I tried adding stretch as an argument to widget/layout and tried command addStrerch() but nothing seems to give any result. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: "unless I put it in a widget, QMenu doesn't work properly" if you are talking about the menu parent, that's a poor choice: you have to choose the *right* parent, not a random one (and certainly not an useless one). Remove that `tool_widget` and change to `QMenu(btn_a)`.

Comment: Thanks! Works! I thought you have to parent most of the widgets to the corresponding layout. What logic is behind choosing a parent for a widget?

Comment: Widgets are automatically reparented when added to a layout. QMenu is a different case, as it appears as a different window, so, unless it's created and shown on the fly, it needs a reference: you either create it with a parent (which could be any other persistent QObject, but it's usually better to make it a child of the object to which it will belong, in this case the button or at least the "main" widget) or you just make it an instance attribute: `self.tool_menu = QMenu()`.

Comment: Also note that, according to your code, `btn_widget_a` is also useless, just add the horizontal layout to the main one: `btn_layout_a = QHBoxLayout()` `self.mainLayout.addLayout(btn_layout_a)`.